# screen reader does not announce anything when closing a TAB

Tags: accessibility

I have worked with NVDA tool for about 6 months. I am testing a webpage where there are multiple TABs opened on the page. Each TAB has different content and also has a close button.

Imagine when the user clicks on the close button on 4th TAB and then the focus immediately switches to the previous TAB close button; however, the screen reader does not announce anything.

currently what is happening is if I click on close button on the current TAB, the TAB will be closed and previous TAB will display and focus remains on the same on the close button on the previous TAB. focus does not move anywhere. so the fix would be focus should be reach on the current opened TAB so screen reader announces the current selected TAB. if its ok ?

How to make it more accessible?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'ARIA=' labels & attributes to ensure that screen readers can accurately convey the purpose of each element.
and also use ARIA live regions to announce changes to tab interface, including when a tab is closed or opened